# Column & Row order in Pandas dataframe selections / indexing into subsets of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Why is the syntax of accessing a dataframe using .loc or .iloc **[row][column]** vs the **[column][row]** order if we index a dataframe using square brackets just as we would use with lists & np.arrays?

I am sure there is a good reason and I am really curious about it :)

```
E.g.

    state   total      Obama     Romney  winner  voters
county                                                       
Adams        PA   41973  35.482334  63.112001  Romney   61156
Allegheny    PA  614671  56.640219  42.185820   Obama  924351
Armstrong    PA   28322  30.696985  67.901278  Romney   42147
Beaver       PA   80015  46.032619  52.637630  Romney  115157
Bedford      PA   21444  22.057452  76.986570  Romney   32189

In [5]: election.loc['Bedford']['winner']
Out[5]: 'Romney'

In [6]: election['Bedford']['winner']
Traceback (most recent call last):................

In [7]: election['winner']['Bedford']
Out[7]: 'Romney'

In [8]: election.loc['winner']['Bedford']
Out[8]: Traceback (most recent call last):.................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best is use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[index_value, column_value]
```

---

```
a = election.loc['Bedford', 'winner']
print (a)
Romney
```

If select by [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html) (`index`) or by `[]` (`column`) only get `Series`.

Second `[]` select value of `column` or of `index` - working with 1d, not with 2d data.

```
#create Series from row Bedford
print (election.loc['Bedford'])
state          PA
total       21444
Obama     22.0575
Romney    76.9866
winner     Romney
voters      32189
Name: Bedford, dtype: object

print (election.loc['Bedford']['winner'])
Romney

#create Series from column winner
print (election['winner'])
county
Adams        Romney
Allegheny     Obama
Armstrong    Romney
Beaver       Romney
Bedford      Romney
Name: winner, dtype: object

print (election['winner']['Bedford'])
Romney
```

and:

```
#no column Bedford
print (election['Bedford'])
```

> KeyError: 'Bedford'

```
#no index value winner
print (election.loc['winner'])
```

> KeyError: 'the label [winner] is not in the [index]'

Comment: Thank you and yes, I agree. Now that you write df.loc[index_value, column_value] I guess that is why the order is row, column rather than column,row -> as the rows are the index that was more important than consistency with the list / np.array slicing?

Comment: Sorry, bad comment before. I think it is hard nice explain why this is implemented this way :)